# How can I include If-None-Match header in HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, http

I have a HttpRequestMessage as follows:

```
string URI = "http://" + MyHostName.DisplayName.ToString() + "/datastore/";

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, URI);
string Params = "";
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));
request.Headers.AcceptCharset.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("utf-8", 0.7));
request.Headers.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("en-us", 0.5));
request.Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Params)));
request.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

try
{
    var result = await client.SendAsync(request);
    var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return content.ToString();
}
catch (HttpRequestException)
{
    Connected = false;
    return "";
}
```

I want to add a `If-None-Match` header to my request with a value like `'8001'` as an example. But when I lookup [HttpRequestHeaders.IfNoneMatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httprequestheaders.ifnonematch(v=vs.118).aspx) you can only get it and not set it.

Any Ideas?

Edit 1: Added that system is running UWP on Windows 10

Comment: You can use `request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation`

Comment: I tried using request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("If-None-Match", 8001) but it didn't return the expected result from the server..

Comment: WJM, how can I know what you want to do? What you post to the server, What your server expects?

Comment: Hi EZI, sorry if I wasn't clear enough. The server expects the If-None-Match header and will send a 304 Response if the ETag from my request matches the ETag on the server.

I only need the technical means to attach an If-None-Match header to my request

Comment: @WJM Have you tried with If-Match ? I tried ` request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("If-Match", "*");` bu doesnot work and throws 501 Not implemented error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution seemed to be a custom addition of a If-None-Match header

For future reference. It may be possible that a server does not accept an ETag in quotes like "8001".

To solve this you can use

```
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("If-None-Match", "8001");
```

This will result in a If-None-Match tag of 8001

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
request.Headers.Add("If-None-Match", "\"8001\"");
```

or

```
request.Headers.IfNoneMatch.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.EntityTagHeaderValue("\"8001\""));
```

I have not tested the second one though.

Comment: Hi Sarathy, I tried both options. The first gives me a ''Value cannot be null" exception.The second one gives me a System.FormatException.

Please note: I am using UWP Api's on Windows 10!

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting a value cannot be null error for first option. For the second option try request.Headers.IfNoneMatch.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.EntityTagHeaderValue("\"8001\""));

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I tried several options but it turned out that the server did not accept the quotes around the number. So "8001" had to be 8001. I got it working using                 request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("If-None-Match", "8001");

Answer (score 0):

Use the EntityTagHeaderValue.TryParse method to safely add an Etag. And be sure to wrap quotes around the string. If you receive an Etag value from a former request these are already included.