# Setting the If-Match in the Headers C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, odata

I have the Odata service, in order to perform a PUT we need to set the Header with `If-Match: *` In Post man I giving like below and it works

[image]

How do I set this If-Match in the Odata Service call to perform a PUT operation.I tried the below

```
 private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PutJsonAsync(string messageBody,string B_Code)
 {
 string userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"];
 string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
 string BaseURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"];

  try
 {
   using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
  {
   var request = new StringContent(messageBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
   string apiUrl = "SAM('" + B_Code + "')";
   request.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
   request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("If-Match", "*");
   var url = string.Format("{0}{1}", BaseURL, apiUrl);
   var creds = userName + ":" + password;
   var credentials = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(creds);
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(credentials));

   response = await httpClient.PutAsync(new Uri(url), request);
 }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
 throw ex;
  }
   return response;
  }
```

But it is not working and throws error `501:Not Implemented`

`response   {StatusCode: 501, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Implemented', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:

OData-Version: 4.0
Date: Mon, 30 Oct 2017 20:42:28 GMT
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=XYZ; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: XYZ;PATH=/;SECURE;HTTPONLY
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 277
Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal
}}  System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage`

Comment: @John updated my question

Comment: Are you setting the content type on your content object? I'm not sure if you're supposed to set it on the request headers.

Comment: @john I followed the answer for the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437925/how-can-i-include-if-none-match-header-in-httprequestmessage

Comment: We need to set the Content Type on the Request right? I am new to this, I tried setting the same for POST and it works. PUT requires the If-Match Header set to work. I am not sure how to add that

Comment: My point was that perhaps you should be setting the ContentType on your *content* object, as in the question you linked. I have no idea if this is your problem, but i've never seen it done the way you're doing it above, and that object isn't only used by HttpClient, so it might be an issue.

Comment: If that doesn't work, proxy your request through something like Fiddler, or use [this site](https://webhook.site) as the endpoint URL, so that you can see what your request actually looks like.

Comment: It works in PostMan if I give if-match in the Header for the request. If I dont give the If-Match then even in the Post man I am getting error code 501. So I guess it is just the If-Match in the header I am not sure how to set that up in the above code

Comment: @john Headers.IfMatch.Add(new EntityTagHeaderValue("*", false)); doesn't work either throws error in IfMatch saying HttpHeaders doesnot have definition for IfMatch

Comment: Yeah, I realised that afterwards. Stupid C#. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "request" object, is your content object, not the HttpRequestMessage object. How did I realise that? ContentType isn't available on the HttpRequestMessage.

`If-Match` is not a content-level header (I don't know why Microsoft make this distinction). You can't add it here, you have to add it to the request header. If you add it to the content object, it gets disregarded.

Something like this should work:

```
string apiUrl = "SAM('" + B_Code + "')";
var url = string.Format("{0}{1}", BaseURL, apiUrl);
var creds = userName + ":" + password;
var credentials = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(creds);
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, new Uri(url));
request.Content = new StringContent(messageBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("If-Match", "*");
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(credentials));

response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

Comment: I think I am doing the same. Sorry for not posting the entire code. I have edited my question. But it is not working and throws 501 error status code

Comment: @xyz No, StringContent is a _content_ object. You are adding If-Match to your content object. You can use `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation`, but I'd recommend against that and recommend that you instead construct a request message as above. It's advised to create a single static HttpClient (as per MSDN docs, and [this](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) link).

Comment: @xyz I've edited my answer to include your specific scenario now that you've included the code.

Comment: Awesome. I have been struggling with this since two days. Thanks a ton.